# web services authentication for j query auto complete text box

Tags: asp.net

I am new to the asp.net web services and i am working on a project which has a auto complete text box for search operation.i am using web services to get the data from data base to the browsers screen . i need to authenticate this web services . only request from my web site auto complete text-box should access this web services with out user login  and deny other request